# iptables NAT with multiple interfaces

Tags: iptables, nat

I have an ubuntu 10 machine I'm trying to set up with NAT.

eth0 is the WAN interface, that uses DHCP.

eth1, eth2, eth3 are LAN interfaces.  They are connected to 192.168.0.50, .51, .52 respectively.

NAT through eth1 works great.  On eth2/3, I get nothing -- "no route to host" on ping.  Here's my iptables config.  Is anything obviously wrong?

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.4 on Mon Jan 31 09:40:55 2011
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1799:327587]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [23:2190]
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE 
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jan 31 09:40:55 2011
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.4 on Mon Jan 31 09:40:55 2011
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [3474:500657]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [24:1613]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [857:128814]
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.50/32 -i eth1 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.51/32 -i eth2 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.52/32 -i eth3 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jan 31 09:40:55 2011
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.4 on Mon Jan 31 09:40:55 2011
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3890:612115]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3474:500657]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [220:45916]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [857:128814]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1140:186789]
-A PREROUTING -i eth1 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x3/0xffffffff 
-A PREROUTING -i eth2 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4/0xffffffff 
-A PREROUTING -i eth3 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x5/0xffffffff 
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jan 31 09:40:55 2011
```

Comment: What does `ip link show` report?

Comment: The output of `ip route show` might also be useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously wrong is using the same /24 on different interfaces.

Comment: What poige said.  If you want eth[123] on the 192.168.0.0/24 LAN, you will need to use interface bonding, assuming your switch supports it.  See many good HOWTOs, such as http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/bonding.html , for more details on that.  Until you stop doing something which is known to cause "unexpected behaviour" (see eg http://pontus.ullgren.com/view/Multiple_interfaces_on_the_same_subnet), you probably won't get much sympathy when complaining about unexpected behaviour!

Comment: switched to put eth1/2/3 on different subnets, everything works great!

Answer (score 2):

As the three Ehternets are in the same network (192.168.0.0/24), maybe you want to bridge them and NAT the bridge device, instead of treating them individually.

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth1
brctl addif br0 eth2
brctl addif br0 eth3

ifconfig br0 192.168.0.50/24 # For example

# Now NAT using br0 as local interface and eth0 as WAN
```